# How to Merge two SmsMessages into a single SmsMessage?

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I create broadcast with following code (from [this article](https://androidexample.com/incomming-sms-broadcast-receiver)):

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getMessageBody();
                        
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message+"; Date="+currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
//sending to API
                   } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
```

But when I receive a long sms (two sms in one),for ex. SMS sent:"bodyOfTheFirstSMS,bodyOfTheSecondSMS", then it is cut to two logs:

```
1) senderNum: +333333333333; message: "bodyOfTheFirstSMS,"; Date=1439968674000
2) senderNum: +333333333333; message: "bodyOfTheSecondSMS"; Date=1439968677000
```

different is only Date of this messages.

**How to check that it's a parts of the one single SMS? Is there any field in SmsMessage, that indicates that this is one message?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to concatenate multi part message by hand. 
In your code you will need to do some modification to handle multipart messages separately as below.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage messages = null;
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                   } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
        SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
        String message;
        try {
            if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {

                String phoneNumber = sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                     message = sms.getMessageBody();
                    Log.info("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message+"; Date="+sms.getTimestampMillis());
//sending to API
            } else {
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
                bodyText.append(messages[j].getMessageBody());
            }
            message = bodyText.toString();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but if I receive messages from different phoneNumbers, it will not crash? Because of, you get first message and then add body from others

Comment: This works perfect even multiple messages from different users received at same time.